# Find Same patterns in lists

Tags: c#, list, pattern-matching

Assume we have below lists:

```
    List<int> Journey1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    List<int> Journey2 = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 4 };
    List<int> Journey3 = new List<int>() { 6, 7, 1 };
    List<int> Journey4 = new List<int>() { 3, 1, 4 };
```

And the patterns are:

```
2, 3, 4 -> Journey1, Journey2;
6, 7    -> Journey2, Journey3;
1       -> Journey2, Journey3, Journey4;
5       -> Journey1;
3, 4    -> Journey2;
3       -> Journey4;
4       -> Journey4;
```

We have 5000 lists, and each has around  200 items, so the patterns can have between 1-200 items and can be seen in 1-5000 lists.

Therefore I need very fast way of pattern matching.

Comment: Can you explain the rules? Eg. Why is it not `3 -> Journey1, Journey2, Journey4`

Comment: Oh, the patterns are (sequence) => (list of lists to search) ?

Comment: we need to find patterns from longest to shortest therefore first I selected 2,3,4 which is longest patter seen in more than one journey.

Answer (score 2):

Without precomputation and with a naive on-the-fly search:

```
var matchedJourneys = journeys.Where(x => ContainsPattern(x, mypattern));

bool ContainsPattern(List<int> list, List<int> pattern)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count - (pattern.Count - 1); i++)
    {
        var match = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < pattern.Count; j++)  
            if(list[i + j] != pattern[j])
                     {
                         match = false;
                         break;
                     }
        if(match) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will execute at max 200 million equals checks for your 'numbers'. But since checks are not expected to be executed for whole patterns, that could be (just a guess) ~5 million equals operations if checking all the lists. That's a few hundred milliseconds.

It all depends on what is 'very fast' for you. If that's too slow, you will need a much much more complicated approach ...

Comment: This is n^2 and it doesn't create patterns to find. Just matches patterns to the lists. Which is only half the job.

Comment: It's unclear if the patterns are known or are yet to be found. I assumed they are known, since the question gives us 'single' item patterns like '1' and '5' (and discovery of such patterns with machine learning doesn't make sense).

Comment: Many thanks Darjan, but as jb said it doesn't create pattern, it should start to create patterns, to create patterns we have simple role each pattern should seen at least in one Journey. at the end of process if some nodes remain on lists which are not in any pattern, we will add them as new patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want as output. I just made a Try.

I suggest that you make a list of lists, instead of declaring individual list variables.

```
List<List<int>> journeys = new List<List<int>>();
journeys.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
journeys.Add(new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 4 });
journeys.Add(new List<int>() { 6, 7, 1 });
journeys.Add(new List<int>() { 3, 1, 4 });
```

I assumed that the numbers range from 0 to 255. With this query

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 256)
    .Select(number => new
    {
        number,
        listIndexes = journeys
            .Select((list, index) => new { index, list })
            .Where(a => a.list.Contains(number))
            .Select(a => a.index)
            .ToList()
    })
    .Where(b => b.listIndexes.Count > 0)
    .ToList();
```

and this test loop

```
foreach (var item in result) {
    Console.Write("Number {0} occurs in list # ", item.number);
    foreach (var index in item.listIndexes) {
        Console.Write("{0} ", index);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

you will get this result

```
    Number 1 occurs in list # 0 2 3 
    Number 2 occurs in list # 0 1 
    Number 3 occurs in list # 0 1 3 
    Number 4 occurs in list # 0 1 3 
    Number 5 occurs in list # 0 
    Number 6 occurs in list # 1 2 
    Number 7 occurs in list # 1 2
```

Where the lists are numbered starting at zero.

Answer (score 0):

For brute force approach you can try to use [polynomial hash-functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) to speed up sub-section matches. Still insane number of comparisons required, but at least match could be almost constant irrespective of sub-sequence length.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there are opportunities to benefit from pattern preprocessing as well as text preprocessing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

For instance, constructing a trie for all subsequences in a list will allow to query this list for a given pattern in time proportional to the pattern length.